# Export pandas dataframe with different data types to csv in python

Tags: string, csv, pandas, geopy

I have a gps parameters data-frame with different types of data (integers, objects, floats, and strings) as follows:

```
  ID              time                speed pdop longitude latitude
0 356363050613605 2017-02-20T17:04:40 210 3.051 8.81640 44.75045
1 356363050637620 2017-02-21T13:44:38 172 60.00 9.41286 45.48268
```

Then by using the geopy package i'have parsed the latitude and longitudes co-ordinates into geographical locations using the following code

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

def f(row):
   loc = str(row['latitude']) + ',' +str(row['longitude'])
   locations = geolocator.reverse(loc)
   return location

df['address'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row), axis=1)
```

which returns an address column to the data-frame with the full address and the co-ordinates as a string.

```
  ID              time                speed pdop longitude latitude address
0 356363050613605 2017-02-20T17:04:40 210 3.051 8.81640 44.75045 (Viale del Lavoro, Zona Industriale C.I.P.I.A.N., Novi Ligure, AL, PIE, 15067, Italia), (44.7524715, 8.8122644)
1 356363050637620 2017-02-21T13:44:38 172 60.00 9.41286 45.48268 (Strada Provinciale 14 Rivoltana, Liscate, MI, LOM, 20066, Italia), (45.4821247, 9.4118136)
```

The problem now that I'm trying to export the data-frame to a csv-file with **"df.to_csv('output.csv')"** but it keeps returning the following error:

> TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

I have even tried the following code which functions only when specifying to return the address column as follows:

```
with open('outpu.csvt', 'w') as file:
    a = csv.writer(file)
    data = df['address']
    a.writerows(data)
```

While when trying to export the whole data-frame it returns an empty file. Any help how to export the whole data-frame to a csv file??

Comment: What does df.dtypes show are the datatypes of your columns?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't need that second set of coordinates. Could those be dropped? One of the issues may be that pandas is reading that as another column.

Comment: Would you get the same error if you wrote as an `xlsx`? Could it be because  your values in the `address` column have commas?

Comment: @Kickaha object, float64, and int64

Comment: @pshep123 sounds reasonable. any idea on how to drop it?

Comment: @qbzenker it returns the same error "TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with geolocator at all, but it appears that your function is returning a list (or tuple) of tuples. If you instead returned something like:

```
return ','.join(location[0])
```

That should return a single string to your `address` column which should be easily writable to csv.

Comment: I have just tried and it leaves me with the following error: "TypeError: ('can only join an iterable', 'occurred at index 0')"

Comment: Ok, so maybe it's already a string. Then just use `return location[0]` and see what happens.

Comment: Now it is working perfectly. thanks for your support